# Is 'Ran out of free Wasm instances' a bad symptom?

Tags: runtime, wasm, offchain-worker

I develop a custom chain based on Substrate.
The chain business logic involves stateful sessions where the state is managed through
Http and unsigned transactions submitted via Offchain workers.

Until recent time the system had 2 offchain workers and worked smoothly.

After a third ow was introduced, the `'Ran out of free Wasm instances'` warning started to pop up and although `--max-runtime-instance 256` seemed to help reduce the warnings' frequency, still they appear.

The ow in question sends an http request, waits for response and based on the result, submits 2 extrinsics, so it looks like no heavy code runs there.
However when I comment the extrinsics submission out the system works normally.

My concern about this story is that the resulting session state changes are not deterministic as for how long in terms of block numbers it takes for the session to switch its states.

I run integration tests based on `subxt` that sometimes succeed and sometimes fail, because it's not always determined at which block the state changes.

As far as I could understand from the relevant `wasm_runtime.rs` code snippets the phenomenon per se doesn't lead to fatal errors, but still I lack insight of what potential consequences this thing can bring.

Is there anything I could do in order to get rid of this sort of trouble ?

Is it advisable to pack all ow logic into a single ow function, rather than run a number of ow in parallel although it looks better from business logic structure perspective ?